# Image is not showing on html page

Tags: html

I am trying to add an image on html page but it doesn't appear

```
 <img href="img/bg.jpeg" alt="welcom" />
```

everything seems to be fine what is wrong with code i test it many times

It test it on two browsers chrome 19 and firefox

I tried the same with another image extension but i doesn't work

```
 <img href="img/2.png"/>
```

where is the problem

Comment: Yes i checked the directory twice

Comment: Learn more at: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Comment: Y href? IMHO href won't support here use src

Comment: I suggest reading the help docs for `<img>` tags before asking a question here. If you'd done a single bit of research on the web about the `<img>` tag, you'd have known you should use `src` here, not `href`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is just in: `href` the attribute

`href` attribute is for ancre link `<a href="#">`

```
<a href="directory">
```

The  `src` attribute is for: `img` tag

```
<img src="directory"/>
```

and if you want to set a background with css you only have to add

```
background-image : url('directory');
```

Trust me its so easy to get confused by this stuff

So i suggest to change href attribute with src

```
<img src="img/bg.jpg" alt="Welcom" />
```

And it should work fine

Answer (score 4):

You're using the wrong attribute, instead of `href` you need to use `src` - the former is for links.

This would be the correct usage:

```
<img src="img/bg.jpeg" alt="welcom" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write

```
<img src="img/bg.jpeg" alt="welcom" />
```

istead of

```
<img href="img/bg.jpeg" alt="welcom" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use src not href to point to the image file name.

```
<html>
<img src="imagefilename.jpg">
</html>
```

This code will display an image with the filename imagefilename.jpg that is in the same directory as this html file